Как избавиться от постоянных запросов в интерактивном режиме файервола ESET?
Установлен ESET Endpoint Security, файервол в интерактивном режиме и с недавних пор (может 2-3 месяца назад плюс минус) при каждой загрузке Windows просятся разные (немного, может 4-5) службы в интернет, но оконцовка названий этих служб постоянно меняется и напрягает постоянно им разрешать/запрещать доступ.
И на многих службах стоит почему-то издатель - Publisher, хотя он не установлен.

